# Issue automatically resizing main title text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am updating a consultancy website that is hosted on [Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com) and I am having sizing issues with the title (it doesn't respond to browser size)

[Here is the link to the webpage](http://www.fabmol.com)

If you resize the page you will see the word eCommerce doesn't resize to fit the screen.

I have tried adding in some custom css but its not working well

```
 @media screen 
 and (min-device-width: 751px) 
 and (max-device-width: 1110px)
{
  #introduction .sqs-block-content h1{
  font-size:100px; 
 }
}
 @media screen 
 and (max-device-width: 750px) 
{ 
 #introduction .sqs-block-content h1{
 font-size:100px; 
 }
}
```

I have since removed the code form the website.

Do you guys have any idea how I can get the main text to resize based on the size of the browser using CSS?

Comment: Does the link above still illustrate the problem? If not, then you've illustrated why we try to discourage links to problems in their live environments - as soon as the issue is resolved, the question is no longer useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right path, but for some reason decided to use `*-device-width` instead of just `*-width`. I'm pretty sure device-width refers to the entire screen size, whereas width will refer to just the browser viewport size. Try this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 1110px)
{
  #introduction .sqs-block-content h1{ font-size:100px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) 
{ 
   #introduction .sqs-block-content h1{ font-size:100px; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For someone, who still has same question, i would recommend to use [fittext](http://fittextjs.com/) plugin.

Non-jQuery standalone version also [exists](https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText();
</script>
```